# Putting a scholarship received for upcoming summer school in CV

Tags: graduate-admissions, masters, cv, summer-school

I applied for a summer school and received a scholarship to attend. In the meantime, I am planning on applying for a Masters, in a field related to summer school, before attending the summer school. Is it acceptable to put the scholarship in the CV?

What would be the appropriate place to put the scholarship? I have a honours and awards section in my CV. But I'm not sure that's the proper place to include the scholarship for the summer school.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. The important date is the date that the scholarship was awarded, not when its associated event will occur.

Let’s take this further, and say that subsequently the summer school is cancelled, and so you don’t actually receive any money to attend it. It would still be perfectly fine to put the scholarship on your CV, as the achievement you are listing is the independent validation of your capability and talents. That judgment stands, regardless of whether the associated event has occurred. Attendance at the summer school itself would be another item on your CV.

A common example is the following: you simultaneously apply for and are offered doctoral scholarships from two different universities. You can only take up one of them of course, but it is still fine to list the other in your CV, with a note that you didn’t take it up. The offers themselves are each evidence of independent validation of your attributes, regardless of whether you actually accept them. Let’s go further and say that you decide not to take up either offer, but leave academia entirely. You would still list both scholarship offers, as they provide useful evidence to a potential employer (i.e. that you chose to leave, rather than that you couldn’t cut it).

So congratulations on your achievement, and never be afraid to claim justifiable credit for it.

Comment: Thanks. What would be the proper place to include it? I have "honours and awards" section but I'm not sure that's the proper place..

Comment: It is an honour that you were awarded, so sure, it fits there.

Answer (score 0):

Sure. Just make clear the scholarship it is for a date/summer school in the future. You could also add sth. like planned/forthcoming/... or the like, to make this point clear.